# How to properly display Firebase Auth error to user using Toast and Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Suppose the user wanted to sign up or sign in to the account. However, the Firebase error appears like this. How can I display the toast notification to the user using try-catch statement with typescript?

```
[FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/email-already-in-use).]
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
    try {
      const credential = await signUpWithEmail(data.email, data.password);
      if (credential.uid) {
        toast.show({
          title: 'Account created! ',
          status: 'success',
          description: 'Welcome!.',
        });
      } else {
        const auth = getAuth();
        auth.signOut();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      toast.show({
        title: 'Cannot sign-up an account.',
        status: 'error',
        description: [CONDITIONAL ERROR MESSAGE FOR DISPLAYING TO THE USER],
      });
    }
```

Edit: add code

Comment: can you please add the code you have tried?

Comment: I just added the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `err` object has a `code` property that you check check in your code, and a `message` property that you can display to the user.

So:

```
  ...
} catch (err) {
  toast.show({
    title: 'Cannot sign-up an account.',
    status: 'error',
    description: err.message,
  });
}
```

See the Firebase documentation on [sending a password reset email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email) that has an example of accessing these two properties.

Also see:

- [Firebase error messages in different languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439504/firebase-error-messages-in-different-languages)
- [list of all auth/ errors for firebase web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152004/list-of-all-auth-errors-for-firebase-web-api)
- [Does Firebase Auth return an Error Code if authentification is not successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65984549/does-firebase-auth-return-an-error-code-if-authentification-is-not-successful)